# Converting utm to lat long with different datums (data?)

Tags: mapping, latitude-longitude, wgs84, utm

I'm a GIS novice, but have code to convert lat/long to UTM coordinates, and it assumes the WGS84 datum.

I also have a list of different values for the earth's radius, roundness, etc:

```
    Datum      Equatorial Radius (m)  Polar Radius (m)  Flattening

    WGS84         6,378,137            6,356,752.3142      1/298.257223563
    Airy 1830  6,377,563.4             6,356,256.9         1/299.32
```

etc...

Is calculating a different projection as simple as substituting these different constants? I can't find anything that supports or refutes this possibility..

Thanks

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such. Can you show us the code that you have so far?

Comment: I'm far too old to still be doing homework..
I grabbed the code off a blog somewhere - they all seem to work ok, but all assume the WGS84 datum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many online tools to perform this conversion, [this one](https://web.archive.org/web/20131122154720/http://www.rcn.montana.edu:80/resources/tools/coordinates.aspx) for instance. That tool provides [this reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20180216112824/http://www.uwgb.edu:80/dutchs/UsefulData/UTMFormulas.htm) which has an excel spreadsheet including the required formulas. In programming terms, you can use [GDAL/OGR](https://gdal.org/) and [PROJ4](https://web.archive.org/web/20161230000425/http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) to effect the conversion seamlessly using Python, for example. Any GIS software package will also be able to reproject the data for you without the hassle.

To answer your last question, no, changing the constants is not sufficient to do the conversion. You are correct, however, that the way the conversion is done is datum-dependent.

Comment: I need to incorporate this into my own software, so I'll have a look at proj4, thanks.

Your link to the reference page with the table of radius values just increases my confusion.
Even assuming these different projections are all TM projections; according to your answer, they cannot be used for conversion without some other values, or a different formula entirely - so why have that list if it cannot be used? Aren't those values irrelevant without the datum location (offset), etc?